# Error when trying to use COPY in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have files in the same Directory than a Dockerfile. I am trying to copy those four files to the container, in a directory called `~/.u2net/`

[image]

This is the Dockerfile code

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.6.0-runtime-ubuntu18.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda.list || true
RUN rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-ml.list || true
RUN apt-key del 7fa2af80
RUN apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/3bf863cc.pub
RUN apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub

RUN apt update -y
RUN apt upgrade -y
RUN apt install -y curl software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
RUN apt install -y python3.9 python3.9-distutils
RUN curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.9

WORKDIR /rembg

COPY . .
RUN python3.9 -m pip install .[gpu]

RUN mkdir -p ~/.u2net


COPY u2netp.onnx ~/.u2net/u2netp.onnx
COPY u2net.onnx ~/.u2net/u2net.onnx
COPY u2net_human_seg.onnx ~/.u2net/u2net_human_seg.onnx
COPY u2net_cloth_seg.onnx ~/.u2net/u2net_cloth_seg.onnx


EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["rembg"]
CMD ["s"]
```

I get the following error

> Step 18/24 : COPY u2netp.onnx ~/.u2net/u2netp.onnx COPY failed: file
> not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat
> u2netp.onnx: file does not exist ERROR

The file `.dockerignore` contains the following

```
!rembg
!setup.py
!setup.cfg
!requirements.txt
!requirements-cpu.txt
!requirements-gpu.txt
!versioneer.py
!README.md
```

Any idea why I can't copy the files? I also tried the following without sucess

```
COPY ./u2netp.onnx ~/.u2net/u2netp.onnx
COPY ./u2net.onnx ~/.u2net/u2net.onnx
COPY ./u2net_human_seg.onnx ~/.u2net/u2net_human_seg.onnx
COPY ./u2net_cloth_seg.onnx ~/.u2net/u2net_cloth_seg.onnx
```

**EDIT:**

I an deploying the container to google cloud run using the command `gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT2}/${SAMPLE2}`

**EDIT 2:**

As I am alrady copying everything with COPY . . , I tried to move the files with the following commands

RUN mv u2netp.onnx ~/.u2net/u2netp.onnx
RUN mv u2net.onnx ~/.u2net/u2net.onnx
RUN mv u2net_human_seg.onnx ~/.u2net/u2net_human_seg.onnx
RUN mv u2net_cloth_seg.onnx ~/.u2net/u2net_cloth_seg.onnx

But I got an error

```
Step 18/24 : RUN mv u2netp.onnx ~/.u2net/u2netp.onnx
 Running in 423d1e0e1a0b
mv: cannot stat 'u2netp.onnx': No such file or directory
```

Comment: how do youse the build command ?

Comment: I am deploying the container to google cloud run using this command : gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT2}/${SAMPLE2}

Comment: Try with removing ~/

Comment: the gcloud submit is for a image that already exists, I'm supposing you are using `docker build -t image:tag -f Dockerfile .`

Comment: @RedaE. no, I am using gcloud builds submit, and then gcloud deploy

Comment: you already used `COPY . .` why don't you move them from the build using `RUN mv`

Comment: @DefSoudani I updated the question. I tried but still have a problem

Comment: Do those `*.onnx` files exist, on the host in the original source tree, in the same directory as the Dockerfile?

Comment: check `.gcloudignore` existence that's what gcloud builds uses

Comment: I ha to add the files to .dockerignore file and then use RUN  mv